# How to build a database based on the output of a AnyLogic model

Tags: anylogic

I want to build a database containing the time of output, along with 3 other variable values of each agent leaving a model through a sink block. Any ideas on how to do it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean writing to the internal AnyLogic database or an external database? The AL help explains how to write to the internal database. (There are no visual elements here; you use Java code to insert/update rows as you require.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you how to do it with time information and 1 additional variable:

```
insertInto(yourdatabasename).columns(yourdatabasename.timeColumn,yourdatabasename.variableColumn).values(dateValue,variableValue).execute();
```

the dateValue can be of time date, and you can use date() instead if you want to capture the exact model time